# AX 2012 R3 Azure Deployment

Tags: azure, lifecycle, demo, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have deployed a Dynamics AX 2012 R3 environment via Lifecycle services and Azure.  The environment is deployed.  I can rdp to the servers in the environment.  I've compiled the application and CIL.  The only company I can "see" is DAT.  I was expecting to be able to access the sample companies.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy from LCS, it creates a default administrator account that you need to login to and add yourself to AX.

Depending on the VM you create, the default user/pass is different.

Go back go https://lcs.dynamics.com and go into your project then click `Cloud-hosted environments`, then single-click on your deployment, and on the right side you will see the Username/Password for the local account.